# Web service method was not found

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services

I had created java web service (using eclipse) with simple method and exported as war to my server. Now when i try to call that web service wsdl , only the wsdl exist but method cannot be processed.

Please suggest what would be the reason?

Comment: Which software you used to create web service? netbeans?

Comment: I used eclipse...I hope that wsdl works but method cannot be called..

Comment: So its a java web service right?

Comment: Yes it was the java web service..

Comment: Is it Axis2 or CXF based webservice?

Comment: Can you post some code or some error that you are getting? (anything in any logs?)

Comment: What do you mean by method cannot be called? You get a server side exception or a SOAPFault is returned?